# Loop to keep asking for guesses when picking numbers in an array (java)

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am writing code to Generate an Array of 100 random numbers between 1 and 100 . 
I then want to ask the user for a number and then search for that number in the array. If the number is present i want to remove it from the array and ask the user for another number. I want to repeat this until the user guesses
incorrectly. If the user guesses incorrectly, I want to output the remaining Array contents in reverse order.

I think I have everything written correctly, but here is my **Question**; **I can't get my head around how to have the program keep asking if the guesses are correct.**

Here is my code, I know it's just a well placed for loop that is needed,I just can't see where. I would really appreciate some help on this. Thank you! I'm not looking for someone to give me the code needed just a steer.

```
int[] randomArray = new int[10];
    // For loop to fill the array with random elements from 1 to 100
    for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++) {
        randomArray[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        // Print the array
        System.out.print(randomArray[i] + ", ");
    }
    // Print a blank line
    System.out.println();

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Declare an int variable to hold the number
    int searchNumber;
    // Ask the user to enter a number
    System.out.println("Please enter a number to search for between 1 and 
100: ");
    // Initialise the int variable with the number entered
    searchNumber = input.nextInt();

    // initialise boolean as false
    boolean found = false;
    // for loop to search the array for the value entered by the user
    for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++) {
        if (searchNumber == randomArray[i]) {
            // If found then set boolean to true
            found = true;
            // If found print out the index where it was found and inform 
the user that it
            // will be removed from the array
            System.out.println("Your number was found at index " + i + " 
and will be deleted from the array:");

            // create a new array which is one element shorter than the 
original
            int[] result = new int[randomArray.length - 1];
            // Copy the the new array from the original array
            System.arraycopy(randomArray, 0, result, 0, i); // i is the 
element to be removed
            System.arraycopy(randomArray, i + 1, result, i, result.length - 
i);
            // Print the new array without the element i
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));

        }
    }

    // code to inform the user if their value was not found and print the 
array in
    // reverse
    if (!found) {
        // Print text telling the user that the number was found and the 
array will be
        // printed in reverse
        System.out.println("Your number was not found, here is the array in 
reverse");
        // For loop to print the array in reverse
        for (int k = randomArray.length - 1; k >= 0; k--)
            System.out.print(randomArray[k] + ", ");

    }

}
```

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I downvoted because, "gimme teh codez."

Comment: It would probably help if you split up your logic into multiple smaller methods rather than having everything in one huge method. I think if you wrote smaller methods and use them together to accomplish your goal you would be able to more easily read your code and decide how to create the loop you need.

Answer (score 0):

Question; I can't get my head around how to have the program keep asking if the guesses are correct.?

Then you should build your logic around some do while loop.

> ```
> //Initialize random values here.
> do{
>      //Get input & process.
>      //Do all Logics.
> }while( exit condition based on your logic else process input again )
> ```

This should do it. I hope.